# How do I create a Trigger to update a time stamp in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

How do I create a trigger in MySQL, so that a column "updated_date" automatically updates whenever a change is made into that table?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: what you want in 'updated_date' the exact time when the changes are made to the table.

Comment: yes i want the exact time when the changes are made..!!

Comment: Remember, the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) does mention doing your homework and research before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a help of trigger.

You may also want to use a MySQL logic - create an TIMESTAMP field with ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP option. It will help you to update date-time value automatically.

[Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Answer (score 1):

Nice question... you can use another table to log all changes, for examle: (price target)

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT into log_table
(user, what, old_with, with, timestamp)VALUES (user(),
NEW.id ,OLD.price, NEW.price),now());
END
```

And if i write the code correctly, you retrice something like this:

user() returns user m

```
root@localhost 1 100 64 2011-12-31 
root@localhost 2 54  32 2011-12-31 
root@localhost 3 28  29 2011-12-31
```